# How to use two instances of HttpClient (one with 2 interceptors and the other one with 1 interceptor) in Angular 4.3?

Tags: angular, http-headers, angular-http-interceptors

In our `Angular 4.3` project, we have public-site components and secured-site (logged in) components separately. We use `@angular/common/http`. We want to implement different http interceptors for `public-site` components and `secured-site` components. For example,

1. public-site components - to apply only below interceptor
   `LoggingInterceptor`
2. secured-site components - to apply below two interceptors
   `LoggingInterceptor`
   `AuthTokenInterceptor` (to pass the auth token in request header)

We tried adding providers details `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` at each component level `@Component` with different interceptors. But the request is not going into any of the interceptors.

The request is going into interceptors only if we add the providers details `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` in `@NgModule`. Here the problem is, public site http requests also go into `AuthTokenInterceptor` which is not needed.

So how should we solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need two instances of `HttpClient` as interceptors getting applied over and over again on each http request.

I do not know how you handling state of our app, based on that you just can put some condition in your interceptor which will decide should current request mutate or or not. This way in case if request is triggering from `public-site components` it wont have a `Authorization` header attached to it. e.g:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if ('your condition here if public-site components') {
        // Just return original request
        return next.handle(req);
    } else {
        // Here return modified one
        // Get the auth header from the service.
        const authHeader = this.auth.getAuthorizationHeader();
        // Clone the request to add the new header.
        const authReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', authHeader)});
        // Pass on the cloned request instead of the original request.
        return next.handle(authReq);
     }

   }
```

If you do not want to send `Authorization` header to particular `api/url` just use `req.url` to set a filter on that.

Comment: Thank you @Kuncevic. We will find the condition to differentiate the public-site components requests. But have a question, if we add HTTP_INTERCEPTORS provider at a @ Component level (removed from @ NgModule) and if we make http calls within ngOnInit method of that component the interceptor is not getting called. If we move the same lines of code (provider) to  @ NgModule, interceptors are working. Should the HTTP_INTERCEPTORS provider configured only in NgModule?

Comment: That is how dependency injection works. Even if you put your `public-site` and `secured-site` in to separate `modules`, each of these obviously you would have to declare in `app.module` and then say in `public-site.module` you specify `interceptor1` and in `secured-site.module` you specify `interceptor1` and `interceptor2` so this way you will end up `interceptor1` calling twice. However if you make each of your modules lazy loaded than you might work it out as each lazy loading module has its own injection tree so providers wont interferer in that case.

Comment: but I wont recommend to work your problem out using `lazy loading` modules as `lazy loading` serving a different purpose. I wont recommend to use `lazy loading` just for sake of having different set of `http interceptors`/`providers` applying for each of your `lazy laded` module, I hope that is clear.

Comment: @Kuncevic Have you found a solution for this? I have the exact same problem. I already tried adding a condition in the interceptor, but I can't find how to filter it out. I have a reference to the request in the interceptor, but not to a referrer, or any info on where the request came from

Comment: @Kuncevic Ignore the question above. Found a way to do it. Feel stupid  I didn't think of it before. You can't get it from the request object, but you can just inject the Router into the interceptor and get the source URL from there